# Modifying folder view in Win10 Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

How can I remove unwanted items from the folder view of `Windows Explorer` in `Windows 10`?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So far, I have try to remove OneDrive from  the navigation in file explorer. Hope it can help you.

1. Run `regedit` as administrator
2. Find the path(there are a large number of keys, we can use search for by Ctrl + F) :`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}`
3. Find the registry : `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree`
4. Change its value date to `0`

---

Update:

For dropbox, you can modify the following registry to remove it. and change the `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` value to `0`.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}
```

Comment: yes, that worked

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article on how to remove entries from Win10 "This PC":
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-the-folders-from-this-pc-win..

But what I use is a free program named WinAeroTweaker: https://winaero.com/
which has many more features for tweaking the look & operation of Win10.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these links. It would be actually good to give a summary of the process, the idea being that web links wont necessarily be there forever...